# Data encapsulation consideration for method parameters (dependency injection)

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

I have a `spec translator`, like below.

```
    //all specifications implement this base class
    public abstract class SpecBase
        {
            public abstract void Translate(IContext context);     
        }

 //spec translator implementation
        public interface ISpecTranslator
        {
            void Translate(IContext context);
        }
```

I need to inject the dependency of the `SpecTranslator` constructor. I have two ways to express the depenency.

Solution 1

```
 public class SpecTranslator:ISpecTranslator
    {
        IList<SpecBase> specs; 

      public SpecTranslator(IList<SpecBase> specs)
        {       
                this.specs = specs;
        }

    }
```

Please note using `IList<SpecBase>` works for now, but seems solution 2 provides more protection.

Solution 2:

```
 public class SpecTranslator:ISpecTranslator
    {
        ISpec spec;
      public SpecTranslator(ISpec spec)
        {       
                this.spec = spec;
        }

  }

    public interface ISpec
    {
        IList<SpecBase> specs {get;}
    }
```

However, the implementation of `ISpec` have the same problem when using constructor dependency injection.

Any idea on pros and cons on these two solutions, or other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in order to "translate" (analyze) the list of specs, the contents of the `ISpec` instance given need to be destructured in all cases. A list has to be obtained and seen through. No matter how many layers of abstraction you weave in, the `SpecTranslator` will finally need a list.

In your case I'd think of `ISpec` as a factory. If the list is not lazily calculated there is no value in it.

Also, simplicity is an important design principle. As `ISpec` does not add any capability or architectural freedom it does not carry its own weight.